# How to disable/enable combo box using a checkbox in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, combobox

I have a dropdown combo box containing a few options for the user. I also have a checkbox that allows the user to use a default value (also in the dropdown combo box). When the user checks the check box, I want to have the combo box become disabled.

My code should work in theory, but it doesn't.

```
Private Sub chkboxUseDefault_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkboxUseDefault.Click
    If chkboxUseDefault.CheckState.Equals(1) Then
        cmbSelectOptions.Enabled = False
    Else
        cmbSelectOptions.Enabled = True

    End If
```

Can someone point out what my (potentially obvious) error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're problem is with: `If chkboxUseDefault.CheckState.Equals(1) Then`

You're code will have the desired outcome if you change that line to:

```
If chkboxUseDefault.CheckState = CheckState.Checked Then
```

Or perhaps even more succinctly:

```
If chkboxUseDefault.Checked Then
```

Although, I am inclined to also agree with OneFineDay in that I find the chkboxUseDefault.CheckedChanged a more appropriate event for this endeavor, and his proposed code is more readable IMO, I felt you might like to know how to make as small a change as possible and achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Lets simplify the check:

```
Private Sub chkboxUseDefault_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles chkboxUseDefault.CheckedChanged
  cmbSelectOptions.Enabled =  Not chkboxUseDefault.Checked
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you see the event I am using? I like it better than the click event for that control.

Comment: Define not working. Did you debug it? What does it show for the values?

Comment: @OneFineDay that should be [Check**ed**Changed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checkedchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (can't edit it's too few characters)

Comment: @OneFineDay Not working as in I would check the checkbox and the dropdown would still be enabled. I'll do more debugging tomorrow morning when I'm in the office and reply back then.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub chkboxUseDefault_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkboxUseDefault.CheckedChanged
    If chkboxUseDefault.Checked = True Then
       cmbSelectOptions.Enabled = False
    Else
       cmbSelectOptions.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

This enables and disables your combobox.